# How do I do a calculation from an input in Python with Regular Expressions?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I perform calculations from an input in Python with Regular Expressions? Like the input would be in the form a string:

```
What is 1+1?
```

So, how do I extract "1+1" from the string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What calculations do you want to support? What input formats do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. extract expression from the input string. The simplest way is using regular expressions:

```
import re
text = 'What is 1+1?'
m = re.search(r'([\d\-+*\\]+)', text)
if not m:
   exit(1)
expr = m[1]
```

2. evaluate expression

```
res = eval(expr)
```

(Note: `eval` is dagerous, but since `expr` has only numerical values it's okay to use it)

2.1. alternatively you can make your own calculator to evaluate the expression

Answer (score 0):

made a short programm:

```
question = input("Please input and press enter:   ")
came_to_math = False
a=0
b=0
c=0
for e in question:
    try:
        int(e)
        if came_to_math:
            b=int(e)
            break
        else:
            came_to_math = True
            a=int(e)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if not came_to_math:
        continue
    try:
        int(e)
    except ValueError: 
        oparator = e

if oparator == "+":
    print(a+b)
elif oparator == "-":
    print(a-b)
elif oparator == "*":
    print(a*b)
elif oparator == "/":
    print(a/b)
else:
    print("NOT SUPPORTED OPARATOR")
```

It only works with the numbers from 0-9!
You can ask questions like:

```
What is 1+2?
What is the result of 3+3?
What happens if I do: 7*5?
please calculate 5/4
```